# segmentation fault (core dumped) in C over array initialization

Tags: c, linux, server, segmentation-fault, malloc

So I have a server code written in C. The first time I execute it (on Linux), it gives a segmentation fault core dumped error. But it always works perfectly when I try again. So I worked my way around to debug it and I have found that my problem lies within the initialization of the client array. I have an array "int clientSockets[1024];" declared at the beginning of my code. When I moved it to a different place in the code (to where I actually start using it), the segmentation fault error has gone but instead I'm getting a bus error. I moved up the declaration of the array back to where it was and used malloc() instead. This time, it has actually worked and my program no longer crashes. But I'm facing a different type of error: my server only accepts 7 clients and then lags forever. It used to accept up to 1020 clients (stored in the clientSockets array).

How do I fix this?

my code is linked below:

```
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netinet/ip.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/select.h>
    #include <errno.h>


    #define ECHO_PORT 9999
    #define BUF_SIZE 4096
    #ifndef FD_SETSIZE
    #define FD_SETSIZE 1024
    #endif


    int close_socket(int sock)
    {
        if (close(sock))
        {
            printf("Failed closing socket.\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        int sock, client_sock; 
        int *clientSockets = malloc(FD_SETSIZE * sizeof(int));  // the problem lies here
        int monitor; 
        int i; 
        fd_set readfds;
        ssize_t readret;
        socklen_t cli_size;
        struct sockaddr_in addr, cli_addr;
        char buf[BUF_SIZE];

        printf("----- Echo Server -----\n");

if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
{
    printf("Failed creating socket.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(ECHO_PORT);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)))
{
    close_socket(sock);
    printf("Failed binding socket.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if (listen(sock, 5))
{
    close_socket(sock);
    printf("Error listening on socket.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}


for (i = 0 ; i < FD_SETSIZE ; i++) 
{
    clientSockets[i] = 0;
} 


while (1)
{

   FD_ZERO(&readfds); 
   FD_SET(sock, &readfds); 
   int nfds = sock; 

   for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(clientSockets) ; i++) 
    {   
        if(clientSockets[i] > 0) 
            FD_SET(clientSockets[i] , &readfds); 
        if(clientSockets[i] > nfds) 
            nfds = clientSockets[i];
    }

    nfds++; 

    monitor = select(nfds, &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL); 
    
    if (monitor < 0) // select() detects error 
    {
        printf("\nERROR:");
        switch(errno)
        {
            case EBADF:
                printf("Invalid file descriptor detected during select().");
            case EINTR:
                printf("A signal was caught during select().");
            case EINVAL:
                printf("Value of nfds is NEGATIVE.");
            case ENOMEM:
                printf("Unable to allocate memory for internal tables");
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    if (FD_ISSET(sock, &readfds))
    {
        cli_size = sizeof(cli_addr);
        if ((client_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &cli_size)) == -1)
            {
                close(sock);
                printf("Error accepting connection.\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            } 


        for (i = 0 ; i < FD_SETSIZE ; i++)
        {
            if (clientSockets[i] == 0) 
            {
                clientSockets[i] = client_sock;
                break;
            }

            if (i == (FD_SETSIZE - 1) && clientSockets[i] != 0)
            {
                printf("Maximum # of clients reached.");
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < FD_SETSIZE ; i++)
    {
        if (clientSockets[i] != 0) 
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(clientSockets[i], &readfds))
            {
                readret = 0;

                if((readret = recv(clientSockets[i], buf, BUF_SIZE, 0)) >= 1)
                {
                    buf[readret] = '\0';
                    printf("client %d (fd:.  %d) sent %s\n",i,clientSockets[i],buf);
                    if (send(clientSockets[i], buf, strlen(buf), 0) ==  -1)
                        {
                            printf("Error sending back echo to client.");
                        } 
                    memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE); 
                }
                if (readret == 0) // client has shut down 
                {
                
                    if (close_socket(clientSockets[i]))
                        {
                          close_socket(sock);
                          printf("Error closing client socket.\n");
                          return EXIT_FAILURE;
                        } 
                    clientSockets[i] = 0;
                }
                if (readret == -1) 
                 {
                     close_socket(clientSockets[i]);
                     close_socket(sock);
                     printf("Error reading from client socket.\n");
                     return EXIT_FAILURE;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}

close_socket(sock);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: You *do* realize that deleting your code is pointless because the edit history is public, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clientSocket` is declared as `int *`. It is a pointer, and a size of a pointer is 8 *no matter what it points to*. The loop

```
for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(clientSockets) ; i++)
```

does 8 iterations, and adds at most 7 clients to the `readfds` (one slot is always taken by the server socket).

I don't know how your original code with `int clientSockets[1024];` looked like. However, my crystal ball tells me that you have had exactly same loop,

```
for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(clientSockets) ; i++)
```

in which `sizeof(clientSocket)` is the size occupied by 1024 integers, that is `1024 * sizeof(int)`. Much more than the array actually holds. Changing it to

```
for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(clientSockets)/sizeof(clientSocket[0]) ; i++)
```

would likely fix the segfault.